# C++11 should raw pointers ever be used when there is one owner (std::unique_ptr) but other objects need a "handle" to the object?

Tags: pointers, c++11

I seem to find quite a lot of code in the following situation:

```
class Thing
{
public:
   Thing() = default;
};

class Repo
{
public:
  Repo()
  {
     // Makes things..
     mThings.emplace_back( std::make_unique<Thing>() );
  } 

  // I find I need functions like this, 
  // a function which may return some record, 
  // or might return nullptr if there is no record.
  Thing* GetThing(int id)
  {
     // Might return nullptr, or might return
     return mThings[0].get();
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>> mThings;
};
```

The object which uses `Repo` to grab a `Thing` doesn't own it, so if it OK/acceptable to use a raw pointer in this situation?

It seems like wrong to enforce it to be a `std::shared_ptr` and return  a `std::weak_ptr` as the caller knows that if `GetThing` doesn't return `nullptr` then the object will live as long as it does. Plus the ownership isn't actually shared.

```
class SomeObj
{
public:
  SomeObj(Repo& repo, int id)
   : mRepo(repo), mMyThing(nullptr), mId(id)
  {
     mMyThing = mRepo.GetThing(mId);
  }
private:
  Repo& mRepo;
  Thing* mMyThing;
  int mId;
};
```

Comment: ``optional<Thing&>`` would be an option (pun intended) but that hasn’t hit STL implementations yet afaik. I return the raw pointer in these cases. But I don’t have any authorative source for answering this…

Comment: could you post an answer explaining what this thing is and how it would be used within my example? I had a look over the boost docs just now but not sure how it would fit in? Would it not cause the object to be copied etc?

Comment: `optional` seems appropriate, but it might be a bit odd to allow lifecycle semantics be exposed to api users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, pure pointers are just enough. But objects that have a handle (pointer) to the `Thing` have to assume that the object being pointed to will outlive them.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [working draft for `std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) and a [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html), which would do something similar to what you need:

```
// make sure to include <boost/optional/optional.hpp>

boost::optional<Thing&> GetThing(int id)
{
    // Might return nullptr, or might return
    return boost::optional<Thing&>(*mThings[0]);
}
```

The `boost::optional` class is supposed to cover cases like yours, where an object *might* be returned, but sometimes it will not. This has been covered in the past by using `std::pair<bool, T>` or using a pointer, if the object to be returned was a reference.

Using `boost::optional` makes semantics more clear, because you

1. state that you won’t always return an object
2. make clear, by returning a reference, that the receiver does *not* take ownership

The usage would be something like this:

```
Repo someRepo;
boost::optional<Thing&> someThing = someRepo;
if (someThing) {
    // use someThing just like a pointer
} else {
    // do not touch the value
}
```

(it might be possible to use `someThing` like a pointer directly; I have not tested this, I built this from the documentation)

**Note**: I’m not entirely sure whether the upcoming `std::optional` will support references. [`boost::optional` does support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/optional_references.html) them. Using a reference is kinda the point here though, because as the OP already noted in a comment on the question, having the bare type here would lead to copying, and using a raw pointer as T would kinda defeat the purpose.

@JohannesD commented a link to [World’s dumbest smart pointer](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf), which is made exactly for this purpose. I have no information about the status of this draft though.

---

*However*: Nowadays, I still tend to use raw pointers in that case, mainly because `std::optional` hasn’t hit implementations (and isn’t even fully specified and might not support references at all) yet. I am also a bit disappointed that it has been removed from C++14.

Make sure to make it clear in the documentation of that function that the receiver does not take ownership.

Comment: Another proposed alternative is the ["World's dumbest smart pointer"](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf).

Comment: @JohannesD That sounds like it was made for this situation. Do you have any pointer on the status of this paper?

Comment: No, other than the fact that it's gone through three revisions already so at least it seems alive and well :)

Comment: [The latest Library Fundamentals TS draft (N3908)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3908.html) says in [5.2/1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3908.html#optional.synop): "A program that necessitates the instantiation of template `optional` for a reference type, or for possibly cv-qualified types `in_place_t` or `nullopt_t` is ill-formed." If I recall the discussion on the standard-proposals mailing list, I think there was lack of consensus on exactly what the semantics of `optional<T&>` should be.

Comment: I suspected such a thing from the cppreference.com website, however, boost::optional supports it. I will change my answer a to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it's acceptable/OK as long as you **NEVER** want to use the code with multiple threads.  If you *might* want to add multithreading in the future, it's a real problem, as the caller has no way of knowing how long the returned pointer will be valid, as another thread might do something that invalidates the pointer.  In such cases a `std::shared_ptr` makes more sense (both in the data structure and as the return value).

Comment: ``std::shared_ptr`` [is not entirely thread safe either](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: I'm sorry, but it has nothing to do with multithreading. There are so many reasons why one object could get deleted before another. `std::shared_ptr` is not suitable for high-performance code. It should  *rarely* be used, when the ownership is _really_ shared. Not as a solution to data races.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: In what way?  The spec guarantees (and that page suggests but doesn't really cover) that if the last two shared_ptrs to an object are destroyed by two different threads, exactly one of the threads will see the refcnt drop to 0 and will destroy the object.

Comment: *If multiple threads of execution access the object referenced by the same shared_ptr without synchronization, a data race may occur unless shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions are used.* Reading again, this might in fact refer to a single shared ``std::shared_ptr`` object being accessed by the same thread. In that case, it would probably not affect the API, assuming that a copy is made when passing it out.

Comment: @JonasWielicki, that cppreference page is **very** poorly worded. The atomic operations for `shared_ptr` don't do anything to prevent data races on "the object referenced by the [...] `shared_ptr`" only races on the `shared_ptr` itself. I think it's trying to say there's a data race when multiple threads access the same `shared_ptr` without synchronisation _and at least one thread uses a non-const member function_, but it's hard to tell. It seems to be trying to talk about two different things in one sentence.